# What does \v and \r mean? Are they white spaces?

Tags: whitespace, lexer

I'm taking a course on lexical analysis, and `\t\v\r` is used in the lexer token definitions to represent white spaces. What are `\v` and `\r` exactly??

Answer (score 32, accepted):

`\t` is a horizontal tab, `\v` is a vertical tab and `\r` is a carriage return.

They are certainly a sub-set of white space characters.

Answer (score 27):

\'  Single quote (')
\"  Double quote (")
\a  ASCII Bell (BEL)
\b  ASCII Backspace (BS)
\f  ASCII Formfeed (FF)
\n  ASCII Linefeed (LF)
\N{name}    Character named name in the Unicode database (Unicode only)
**\r    ASCII Carriage Return (CR)**
**\t    ASCII Horizontal Tab (TAB**)
\uxxxx  Character with 16-bit hex value xxxx (Unicode only) (1)
\Uxxxxxxxx  Character with 32-bit hex value xxxxxxxx (Unicode only) (2)
**\v    ASCII Vertical Tab (VT)**