# '.' is not recognized as valid command

Tags: python, windows

On Windows (11), I'm trying to activate a python virtualenv inside a `subprocess.run`, but, I'm not able to execute the activate script :

```
import subprocess

p = subprocess.run(".\venv\Scripts\activate.bat", shell=True, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
print(p.stderr)
```

Produce :

```
b"'.' n'est pas reconnu en tant que commande interne\r\nou externe, un programme ex\x82cutable ou un fichier de commandes.\r\n"
```

**Note**: `.\venv\Scripts\activate.bat` is working in a shell prompt.

How am I supposed to activate a virtual env inside a `subprocess.run` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember that `\` is used to escape special characters. `\v` is a [ASCII Vertical Tab](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20298707/1707427), so that the first part of your command line is just `.`. To fix this, add an `r` to your string.

```
p = subprocess.run([r".\venv\Scripts\activate.bat"], stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Note that I've also removed the shell=True. It's not necessary and so shouldn't be used.

Oh, and remember that you cannot change one process' environment from a subprocess. So, whatever you're trying to do, probably won't work anyways.

Comment: An alternative is to use double-backslashes: ".\\venv\\Scripts\\activate.bat".

Comment: @EricMcLachlan yeah, but that way lies madness. I always forget to double one of the slashes :)

Comment: @EricMcLachlan Thanks for removing your answer, btw. Recognizing when you're wrong shows true greatness!